# append и мутируемость слайса

Tags: golang

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    arr := make([]int, 3, 3)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    addElems(arr)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
}
func addElems(arr []int) {
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 5)
    arr = append(arr, 6)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
}
```

Слайс мутирует внутри функции, так устроен гоу, но если если делать append, то всё работает иначе. я думаю, это вероятно, потому что append возвращает новый адрес и вставляет в переменную arr, но не понятно почему сама arr не мутировала.

Я решил сделать другой пример

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    arr := make([]int, 3, 8)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    addElems(arr)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
}
func addElems(arr []int) {
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 5)
    arr = append(arr, 6)
    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
}
```

Тут append ни разу новый адрес не вернул, почему тогда на выходе из функции arr один, а в после работы функции в меине он уже другой?

Comment: Кто-то очень хочет попасть в wildberries school ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Срез - это не указатель. Это структура данных из трёх полей, которая в функцию передаётся **по значению**.

Вот, смотрите:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := make([]int, 3, 3)
    fmt.Println("main: ", arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    fmt.Printf("main: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
    addElems(arr)
    fmt.Println("main: ", arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    fmt.Printf("main: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
}
func addElems(arr []int) {
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 5)
    arr = append(arr, 6)
    fmt.Println("  ", arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
}
```

```
main:  [0 0 0] 3 3
main: 0xc000010018->0xc00001a018
  addElems: 0xc000010060->0xc00001a018
   [0 0 0 4 5 6] 6 6
  addElems: 0xc000010060->0xc000108000
main:  [0 0 0] 3 3
main: 0xc000010018->0xc00001a018
```

В `main` переменная `arr` находилась по адресу `0xc000010018`, указатель на данные был `0xc00001a018`

Но в функции `addElems` все операции происходят с совсем другим объектом, лежащим в памяти по адресу `0xc000010060`. То. что в этом объекте изменился указатель, никак не отображается на первом объекте. Аналогично с `len` и `cap` - они изменились в значении, которое лежит на стеке `addElems`, но эти изменения никак не отразились на исходный объект.

В случае `make([]int, 3, 8)` указатель не изменился, так как не потребовалась переаллокация. Но и в этом случае исходный слайс ничего не узнал об изменениях в копии, поэтому `len` и `cap` не изменились, несмотря на добавление трёх элементов.

Если вам нужно, чтобы обновился исходный объект, то нужно либо передавать указатель

```
func addElems(arr *[]int) {
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", arr, *arr)
    *arr = append(*arr, 4)
    *arr = append(*arr, 5)
    *arr = append(*arr, 6)
    fmt.Println("  ", *arr, len(*arr), cap(*arr))
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", arr, *arr)
}
```

либо возвращать изменённый объект

```
func addElems(arr []int) []int {
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 5)
    arr = append(arr, 6)
    fmt.Println("  ", arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    fmt.Printf("  addElems: %p->%p\n", &arr, arr)
    return arr
}
```

Стайл гайд рекомендует второй способ, с возвратом обновлённого значения.

Answer (score 1):

сам по себе массив под слайсом `arr` мутируется, это можно увидеть, прописав `arr = arr[:cap(arr)]` в `main` после `addElems(arr)`, что создаст новый слайс с длиной, равной вместительности массива, на основе того же массива.

слайс `arr` из `addElems`, это слайс, созданный на основе слайса из `main`.

более подробно о массивах и слайсах можно почитать тут: https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

можете сократить логи так: `fmt.Printf(“%p %v len=%v cap=%v\n”, arr, arr, len(arr), cap(arr))`

Answer (score -1):

append работает с копией а не с базовым массивом

И если нужно чтобы append новый адрес вернул, добавьте больше 3х значений.

append создает новый слайс c cap= cap(старый слайс)*2 а пока ему cap старого хватает, он в него и аппендит.

Получается, чтобы адрес изменился нужно добавлять больше чем cap(arr)

```
func main() {
    arr := make([]int, 3, 8)
    // fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    // log.Printf("%p", arr)
    addElems(arr)
    // fmt.Println(newArr, len(newArr), cap(newArr))
    // log.Printf("%p", newArr)
}

   func addElems(arr []int)  {
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)

    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)

    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)

    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)

    arr = append(arr, 4)
    arr = append(arr, 4)
    log.Printf("%p", arr)

    fmt.Println(arr, len(arr), cap(arr))
    log.Printf("%p", arr)
    
}
```

У меня вывод такой:

```
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc000020200
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc000020200
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011a000
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011a000
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011a000
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011c000
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011c000
[0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4] 19 32
2024/03/06 13:05:50 0xc00011c000
```

Адрес меняется при каждом расширении cap(то есть каждом копировании в новый базовый массив)